# How to list blogger posts by label in alphabetic order

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, blogger, alphabetical

I am trying to list my blog posts under a specific label in alphabetic order. Since I am not a programmer, I found this code from internet, which lists all my posts labeled "subtitles" in a chronological order. I didn't find any way to sort the result in alphabetic order. Previously I was using yahoo pipes for this purpose, since yahoo pipe no longer exists this kind of code is very much needed. Any other code which might give the proposed result is also appreciated.

```
<!-- Recent Posts by Label Start -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function recentpostslist(json) {
 document.write('<ol>');
 for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++)
 {
    for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
  if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') {
        break;
  }
}
var entryUrl = "'" + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + "'";//bs
var entryTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
var item = "<li>" + "<a href="+ entryUrl + '" target="_blank">' + entryTitle + "</a> </li>";
document.write(item);
}
document.write('</ol>');
}

</script>
<script src="http://www.malayalamsubtitles.org/feeds/posts/summary/-/subtitles?max-results=500&alt=json-in-script&callback=recentpostslist">  </script>
<!-- Recent Posts by Label End -->
```

Comment: i found a solution. not a direct one though. created an API from the list generated by the code given in question. (with help of kimonolabs application). after that i created a new page to out put the feed result alphabetically. since it was explained in another question i will give the link.. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146801/sort-jquery-result-alphabetically/33146861[/link]

Comment: Link seems broken. Please check.

Comment: @DaniSpringer sorry, my mistake. try this link >> [updated-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146801/sort-jquery-result-alphabetically/33146861)